# htaccess redirect image folder to root

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, content-management-system

I have a directory called "public_html/hammer/" (my CMS). I want to use the image folder that is on the root "public_html/". I could simply do something like "../picture.jpg" but the content within "/hammer/" will be show on the root directory so it will then be broken when I query the html.

How can I write an ModRewrite or similar that will point "public_html/hammer/images/" to "public_html/images"?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming public_html is your document root, place a rule like the following in `public_html/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^hammer/images/(.*)$ images/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Ok this worked! thanks! I just needed to update my rewrite base.

Answer (score 1):

Basically:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^.*$ ../../$1 [L]
```

Comment: Can you elaborate more this? Doing just this will redirect everything. Can it be more specific?

Comment: Is it possible to do an alias of sorts?

Comment: My .htacces was mean to be in the images folder, not in the root :P